# Stat/Transfer 13 SAS 9 to Stata 14 date variable

Tags: sas, stata

I am trying to convert a sas 9 file to stata 14 using `DDMMYYp10`. inside my sas file for dates.

Stattransfer13 is transferring my date variables as intiger and not in a date format to Stata 14.

I tried to use the `date-fmt-write` options inside stattransfer 13, without success.

Comment: You have a problem with files we can't see and a proprietary program. Unless someone is familiar with a similar problem, this sounds like a question for the company's technical support.

Comment: Indeed I wrote them because I think it might be a bug. The SAS Date Formats are incorrectly converted. `MMDDYYp10.`is converted to `DDMMYY` in Stata and `DDMMYYp10.` is converted to an integer. The Format `date11.` works fine though.

Comment: @NickCox StatTransfer is a program commonly used by programmers (in a particular field), so I think this is a reasonable question.  Not one I know the answer to, mind you, and well possible it is a bug, but it could also be something solveable.

Comment: @Joe Quite so. (Years ago, I had a licence, not that it matters.) I didn't vote to close. My comment was based on the best way to get an answer on that information.

Comment: This presumably is an issue with StatTransfer reading a SAS date value (which, as I'm sure you are aware, is a numeric value in SAS) and outputting it as numeric. I just tested with StatTransfer 11 and observed similar behavior. Basically, I think StatTransfer has no way of knowing that some numeric value is supposed to map to some date. Or perhaps it would if it were read into SAS with the proper informat? I'm not sure. Perhaps write out the dates as strings in SAS and work from there.

Comment: I am in contact with the customer, gonna keep you updated if I find a solution.

Answer (score 2):

This is Stata solution, rather than a StatTransfer one.

SAS stores dates as integers, with a zero of January 1, 1960. `mmddyyp10.` is just a format that puts a period between components, so 18031 looks like 05.14.2009 after `FORMAT datevar mmddyyp10.;` (if I recall the SAS syntax correctly).

Conveniently, Stata uses the same coding convention for dates. You just need to `format datevar %tdNN.DD.CCYY` in Stata:

```
. display %tdNN.DD.CCYY 18031
05.14.2009
```

Comment: We just use `date11.` in sas now, which can be correctly transferred by stattransfer13. I guess its a bug in the new stattransfer software.